# check multiple usernames to display edit privilege

Tags: php

I have an edit button on my site for users to edit comments they have written.  It appears only on posts that the logged in user has written through performing this check.

```
if($rows['name']===$_SESSION['myusername']
```

I want to allow the admin account to also be able to edit any posts.  How would I add the user account for admin to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us some more information? How do you know who the admin is for example?

Comment: `if(($rows['a_name']===$_SESSION['myusername']) OR ($myusername===$_SESSION['admin']))` doesnt seem to work. Instead it allows edit privilage to all users

Answer (score 0):

Add in `if` statement or condition to check if current user is admin.

```
if( $rows['name']===$_SESSION['myusername'] || $_SESSION['idAdmin'] ) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that every login is checked and a users privileges are passed into a variable, for example:

```
$_user['loggedin'] = false;
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && isset($_SESSION['mypassword'])) {
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername'])."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['mypassword'])."'");

  if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 1) {
    $_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $_user['loggedin'] = true;
  }
}
```

Now assuming you have a field 'is_admin' on your database, you can use this piece of code in your check:

```
if($rows['name'] == $_SESSION['myusername'] OR ($_user['loggedin'] && $_user['is_admin'])) { // perform action }
```